# How to allow AppCenter to auto-update apps as in Android's Play Store?

Tags: updates, appcenter, permissions

How to allow *AppCenter* to auto-update all the apps as it happens in *Android*'s *Play Store* or in *Microsoft Windows*?

It is a little annoying to give permission every time to update the apps. And if one does not update the apps, the red dot on the *AppCenter*'s icon would not go away.

Comment: Good question, I think that would be something difficult to do, something that characterizes Linux is security, so every time an application makes changes to the system, such as updates, it asks for authorization to do it as an administrator (root).